# Could not able to sync my project in Android studio,Getting following error

Tags: android, kotlin

Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.41/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.41.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication Required

But in my proxy settings connection establish is successful

Answer (score 0):

If you are working **behind a proxy** then you have to specify that in the project too.

Goto **File**-> **Settings** -> Under **Appearence & Behavior** -> Under **System Settings** -> **HTTP Proxy** -> Click on **Manual proxy configuration**, and add the neccessary details.

Then goto your **gradle.properties** file which should contain something like this :

```
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=your_password
systemProp.http.proxyHost=host_Ip_address
systemProp.http.proxyUser=your_username
systemProp.http.proxyPort=port_number
```

Add this to your file, along with the above :

```
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=your_password
systemProp.https.proxyHost=host_Ip_address
systemProp.https.proxyUser=your_username
systemProp.https.proxyPort=port_number
```

These details can be found out from your browser's proxy settings.

If this does not work, then please check your home directory ("C:/users/username") check for a hidden folder "**.gradle**". Check the contents of the **gradle.properties** in that folder. If there is a file, either delete it, or edit it and add the above code in that file as well.

Comment: I have done with proxy settings and in gradle.properties file,but still it occurs

Comment: have you added both the http and https section in your code? Both http and https section are required. Also check if the details that you provided in gradle.properties are correct.

Comment: systemProp.http.proxyPassword=XXXXX
systemProp.https.proxyUser=XXXXXXXX
systemProp.https.proxyPort=XXXXXX
systemProp.http.proxyHost=XXXXX
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=XXXXXX
systemProp.https.proxyHost=XXXXXXX
systemProp.http.proxyUser=XXXXXXXX
systemProp.http.proxyPort=XXXXXXX

Above lines added in my gradle.properties

Comment: Could you also check if offline mode is enabled on Android studio..? You can check whether offline is enabled in Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle

Comment: If offline is enabled then disable it.

Comment: ,It's in disable mode only

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check that as well.